# Showing picture for latest post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to show the picture belonging to the newest post at the top of the page and then the rest of the posts below but without pictures. Right now it shows the first posts picture but beside every post. I think this is because I have @post.each in my view but I am not sure what to change it to.
Here is my post function:

```
def index
@post = Post.order("created_at DESC").limit(1)
end
```

And here is how I call it in my index view:

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not store the first post in a different instance variable?

EG:

```
def index
 @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC")
 @first_post = @posts.shift
end
```

And in the index view show the @first_post before looping over the @posts

PS: I'm not entirely sure about the "shift" method there. The idea is to pop the first element.

PS2: The code you posted should output only one post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess I should have shown all of the index function. @post is my first post and then I have '@posts' for displaying all of them.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I'm really new to stackoverflow so it was hard to find out you read the answer. Anyway, if you have different instance variables for the first post and all the posts, why iterate over `@post` since it is only one element? Be aware that your `@posts` variable would include the first post as well.